# Linker error with flex

Tags: c, clang, linker-errors, ld

I just finished compiling and installing flex for my macbook pro and tried to compile a file using flex. I get the following error:

```
ld: library not found for -lfl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [myhtml2txt] Error 1
```

I believe `-lfl` is the linker for flex, so why am I getting this error, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Not sure about MAC, but you seem to be missing `libfl`, whatever that is. Perhaps that should be `libflex`?

Comment: @Olaf where do you see "`libfl`"?

Comment: Pleasee read the clang/ld documentation, command line options. `-lfl` tells ld to link `libfl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing to add libflex or it could be libfl. your main error `ld: library not found for -lfl`tells that library is missing. l in -lfl denotes the library. by adding library you will not see this error